# C++ Run Command Error ./ is a directory

Tags: c++, coderunner

I am using the Coderunner app for Mac OS X to mess around with some c++ code.  However, whenever I run any c++ program (including when the program is blank) I get this same error -
`Run Command: line 1: ./: is a directory`  I cannot figure out why this is happening, even after I searched for hours.  I have installed the newest Xcode (5.0.2) and the command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

icehockey38

Go to "preferences" in CodeRunner and select the option "languages" then at the bottom of the list there is a button that says "Reset", click that and you should get the original way that the languages scripts came with. I was getting the same error message I did that and it work.

Good luck.